# Why is it that when executing `build docker` I persistently see EOF?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, python-docker

Having gone through different solutions provided on this platform and surfing the web, my error keeps popping up again and again.

I am inclined to drop my question this time around.

While running `docker build -t myimage .`, I keep on seeing the following error output

```
...
#5 sha256:092586df92068bd6b59c497f379e48302aa1b27cf76b2de64d262ba7bc19e47b 2.10MB / 45.38MB 316.4s
#5 sha256:87fc2710b63fcf6c0a5c876b1b37773d9e949cb4d66eeb06889ef84f7b5a5a93 25.17MB / 214.83MB 964.5s
#5 DONE 966.7s

#7 [2/5] COPY . /app
#7 sha256:0930007e6ec71d357846ab0d691d72a68ae6ef349d84b3a69cec532b93def08c
#7 ERROR: failed to read expected number of bytes: unexpected EOF
------
 > [2/5] COPY . /app:
------
failed to compute cache key: failed to read expected number of bytes: unexpected EOF
```

Here is my Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:stretch

# Use the `python:3.7` as a source image from the Amazon ECR Public Gallery
# We are not using `python:3.7.2-slim` from Dockerhub because it has put a  pull rate limit.
# FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.7:latest
# FROM python:3.7
# Set up an app directory for your code
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
# Install `pip` and needed Python packages from `requirements.txt`
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Define an entrypoint which will run the main app using the Gunicorn WSGI server.
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "main:APP"]
```

Also, this is my project structure:

```
    CODEOWNERS  
    __pycache__/        
    buildspec.yml               
    main.py           
    test_main.py
    Dockerfile  
    app/                
    ci-cd-codepipeline.cfn.yml  
    requirements.txt 
    README.md   
    aws-auth-patch.yml  
    iam-role-policy.json        
    simple_jwt_api.yml  
    venv/
```

I was asked to create app directory but this couldn't work. I would be pleased to have it resolved.

- Note: my docker desktop is running perfectly.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/2568